# How do I change the root path of Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

A site was recently migrated but it seems it wasnt done properly.

The path seems to be saying `/home/example/domains/example.ie/public_html`

I know this because when I try use certain plugins like WP Super cache Im getting an error saying

> Warning! Could not update
>   /home/example/domains/example.ie/public_html/wp-config.php!
>   WPCACHEHOME must be set in config file.

My ACTUAL path is simply `/public_html` now

I have search wp_options for an obvious definition of where the path is set but nothing is showing up.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you wp-config.php is not writable. Check wp-config.php permissions and set them to 664. If this does not work, change them to 666 or 777, do the work you want to do and return back to 664, never left wp-config.php premissions to 666 or 777 because the site can be hacked easy.